# How do you say "light beer" in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

I've found several possible translations, but none that seem to be generally used, at least according to my googling:

- *bière allégée*
- *bière basses calories*
- *bière faible en calories*
- *bière « light »*

Which is the most idiomatic term for low-calorie beer?

Comment: Low cal. I hadn't realized that "light beer" could mean either one - I'll edit my question.

Comment: In daily life, we rather use *bière light*. It is also called as such in shops.

Comment: On appelle ça une Kro ou une Heineken / We call it a Kro or a Heineken ;)

Comment: In Québec, we would say : de la ''light''

Comment: Do you plan on using this phrase in a specific context? If it's to order it at a bar, you need to ask for “bière sans alcool” or settle for a light pils/pale lager like, indeed Kronenbourg, 1664, Jupiler, etc. You won't find anything else. Incidentally, I am not sure what's “light” in a product like “Bud light” because it's actually very similar to the regular pils served in France.

Comment: I can't speak for France, but in Belgium, there is no such thing as light beer: [Belgian Beer poster](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztu9V.jpg) The closest you could come to express that kind of vile concoction would be: *De la pisse américaine* ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Not really idiomatic but I believe ***bière light*** is much more used than the other suggestions, at least in France.

If avoiding the anglicism is needed, I would use *Bière légère*<sup>*</sup> like [Coors](https://www.saveur-biere.com/fr/bouteilles/2219-coors-light.html) is doing, all remaining choices (*allégée, basse calories, faible en calories*) being more or less unattractive.

I wouldn't use *bière sans alcool* either, given the fact well known light beers like Bud Light and similar are not alcool-less.

<sub>* As the various comments and other answers clearly show, "Light beer" is already ambiguous is English. Retaining "Light" in *Bière light* or using the controversial *légère* in *Bière légère* to translate "light" keeps this ambiguity which is what a good translation should do, imho.</sub>

Comment: +1 for “bière light” but “bière légère” is definitely out, almost everybody would understand a light-bodied blond beer.

Comment: @Relaxed That's precisely why I would choose "bière légère", which looks to be commonly used in Quebec. All remaining suggestions (allégée, basse calories, faible en calories) are more or less unattractive. Also, well known light beers like Bud Light or Coors Light are not "sans alcool".

Comment: @jiliagre That might be Québec-specific then, in France that's what you would get when ordering “une bière” or “un demi” anyway, so “légère” does not really make sense.

Comment: @Làchus'n'AI "Light beer" doesn't seem to be well defined in English. *Légère* is clearly keeping this fuzziness so looks a good translation to me ;-)

Comment: There is no such thing as “1664 légère”, I still find the translation very misleading in this context, fuzziness or not.

Comment: @Relaxed Your are correct, there is no "1664 légère" and likely never will. Should Kronenbourg decide to launch it, that would probably be under the brand "1664 Light". That's why I wrote in my answer: "**If avoiding the anglicism is needed**". The fact is there is no such need in France, especially for a brand here. On the other hand, that need definitely exists in Quebec where, guess what, *légère* is used.

Comment: @Relaxed I suspected it might be Québec-specific (see my second comment) but then it ought to be explicitly specified in the answer. Originally, it read to me as if “bière légère” is a common label for a specific type of beer across French-speaking countries.

Answer (score 2):

I would say “light” as it is the most idiomatic way to say “low-cal” in French when referring to soda and other beverages. “Allégé” is sometimes used as well, e.g. for cream.

But I must say I don't recall ever seeing such a beer anywhere in France. French people tend to classify beer mostly by colour, even if it's a bad proxy for taste, and possibly by their alcohol content. That might be why you failed to find any common phrase for this.

What you will find instead is low-alcohol beer, which is inherently low-cal, but it's not called that. It's called “sans alcool” or “0%” instead (there is a subtle difference, “0,0%” only appeared recently with better filtering techniques, older “no alcohol” beers do in fact contain a little alcohol).